# remove object at NSMutableArray in range

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsmutablearray

I am trying to remove objects at array starting at index 5 to the end of the list. I have a for loop to do this, however now I discovered

```
 - (void)removeObject:(id)anObject inRange:(NSRange)aRange
```

The question is what is the anObject here? I only need range as far as I know

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`removeObject:inRange:` deletes an object within a certain range. This method would be useful if you wanted delete the string `@"Hello World"` only if it is one of the first 5 elements.

It sounds like what you are trying to do is delete all objects after the 5th element. If that is what you are trying to do, you should use the `removeObjectsInRange:` method. For example:

```
 NSRange r;
 r.location = 5;
 r.length = [someArray count]-5;

 [someArray removeObjectsInRange:r];
```

Comment: You can also use the NSMakeRange(location, length) function to specify the range.

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
- (void)removeObjectsInRange:(NSRange)aRange
```

> Removes from the array each of the objects within a given range.

Comment: +1 - Xcode's quick documentation on the side only mentioned that `NSMutableOrderedSet` had this as a method, so I didn't think it was the right method to use. But then I checked `NSMutableArray`'s documentation and saw it actually had a method with the exact same signature.